# how to find xpath of a dropdown list items in chrome browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, odoo

I am using chrome browser for selenium webdriver automated testing 
By using google developer tools , it is easy to find simple xpath but I can't able to find out the drop down list item path in that , in firefox it is working , but in chrome it is not

I am sticking one image

[image]

Help me to find out the path of

Answer (score 0):

First using arrow(ctrl + Shift + C) select the dropdown.

Now the element HTML code is automatically selected.

Now right click on the selected HTML code -> Copy -> Copy Xpath

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: ya that's true but from this , u can't get absolute path for id changing elements that is dynamic elements . We only find static path

Comment: There is no tool avaiable for dynamic xpath as per I know. You need to write your Xpath your own for dynamic xpath as an example if drop down id or something  is different then pass it in xpath as string example +id+       "li[contains(.,'+id+')] ".

Answer (score 0):

k thanks @subham for your help , there is one way that in firefox we can use firepath plugin to find absolute path & then extract that path and then use the same path in chrome , I am not sure but it may works

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("oe-fiels-input-62")));
dropdown.selectByText("[A1090] iMac");
```